# How to reorder pairs in a dictionary (python)

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to reorder a dictionary from:

```
{'peaches: fruit': 2,
 'cake: dessert, kale: vegetable': 1,
 'carrots: vegetable': 1,
 'pears: fruit': 1}
```

to:

```
{'fruit:peaches', 'dessert:cake', etc.}
```

Would appreciate some advice on how to do that!

Comment: For that matter, the original `dict` looks nigh useless. Are you sure the complete string `"peaches: fruit"` (which looks like a key/value pair in a `dict`, but is just a key) should be a key mapping to an `int`?

Comment: Is `vegetable:kale` supposed to be in the result?

Comment: Your question seems wrong, look at the second line, <'cake: dessert, kale: vegetable': 1, > To be correct, it must have a number after the word dessert. Isn't it?

Comment: @Droid-Bird The number 1 is after vegetable

Answer (score 0):

That will do it:

```
import re

old_dict={'peaches: fruit': 2,
          'cake: dessert, kale: vegetable': 1,
          'carrots: vegetable': 1,
          'pears: fruit': 1}

new_dict={re.sub(r'(\w+): (\w+)',r'\2: \1',key):value 
          for key,value in old_dict.items()}
```